# How to instantiate Firebase Cloud Messaging in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

How to instantiate Firebase Cloud Messaging in Angular2 / TypeScript / AngularFire2 ?

It's described here for JavaScript:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `firebase.messaging()` function takes the Firebase app instance as an optional parameter.

To wire it up with `AngularFire2`, you could let `AngularFire2` [perform the app initialization](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md#4-setup-ngmodule) and create the Firebase app instance and could then inject the app instance (into a service, for example) and pass it to `firebase.messaging()` like this:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseApp } from "angularfire2";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    private _messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging;

    constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) private _firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {

        this._messaging = firebase.messaging(this._firebaseApp);
        this._messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(() => { ... })
            .catch((error) => { ... });
    }
}
```

You'll need to setup the [web app manifest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_the_browser_to_receive_messages) that's mentioned in the article you referenced. That's something with which I am unfamiliar.

Comment: Thank you for you reply !
When I declare ```private _messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging; ``` I get : ```[ts] Module 'firebase' has no exported member 'messaging'.
any
```
?

Comment: What version of `firebase` are you using? I thought I checked it before posting the answer. I'll double check it.

Comment: I have just ```"angularfire2": ">=2.0.0-beta.6"``` in my package.json. 
It has ```"firebase": "3.3.0"``` as dependency in its package.json.
see: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/package.json#L43

Comment: I'm using a slightly earlier version of `angularfire2` (2.0.0-beta.5), but I'm using `firebase` 3.5.3. It includes the typings for the messaging bits and I don't see the error you mentioned.

Comment: Manually. I have it as a dependency in my `package.json`. `angularfire2` has it as a `dependency`, but it should really be a `peerDependency`. If you uninstall `angularfire2`, add a `firebase` dependency of your own to your `package.json` and re-install, you should be in the same situation as me. (There is an issue open for the `angularfire2` `peerDependency` thing. Hopefully, it will be resolved, eventually.)

Comment: That dependency was annoying, i solved it with going into the node_modules --> angularfire2  and deleted the node_modules folder containing the firebase dependency

Comment: OK no more type errors anymore, but when I run my app in Chrome , an error is thrown:
```"Messaging: The required permissions were not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked)."```
maybe its related to that missing manifest.json

In FireFox I get a popup which asks for permission, and I don't get an error

Comment: @daslicht Yes. You will need to do whatever configuration is mentioned in that article you referenced. This answer dealt only with wiring things up so that `firebase.messaging` would play nice with AngularFire2's infrastructure - as it insists upon creating the Firebase app instance, etc.

Comment: anything fine, it was just a chome setting. I don't get any errors anymore and the question has been solved !

Comment: I'me having problem getting a token. Can you uys please have a loot [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912591/fcm-gettoken-doesnt-return-anything)?

Comment: awesome answer, all the official demo doesn't have  this way of firbase app injection.
this line you need all those demo to work:import { FirebaseApp } from "angularfire2", thanks for such a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an import that is required:

```
import '@firebase/messaging';
```