# FCM getToken() doesn't return anything

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I'm trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging with Angular2 but it's like they don't want us to do that @Google.

I've been following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460240/how-to-instantiate-firebase-cloud-messaging-in-angular2) to be able to stop errors.

I'm now facing the following problem:
**Why does `messaging.getToken()` returns nothing?**
No error, no token in the console, nothing.

Any help is more than welcome. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I've updated the code bellow with my try using `onTokenRefresh()`. It does not change anything. I feel like it comes from the fact that I'm not really plugged to my firebase files. Anybody have been able to make FCM with Angular2 and AngularFire2?

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp } from "angularfire2";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './+config.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./+config.component.scss']
})
export class UserConfigComponent implements OnInit {

  private _messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging;

  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) private _firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    this._messaging = firebase.messaging();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
    this._messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
      this._messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(refreshedToken) {
          console.log('Token refreshed.', refreshedToken);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
        });
    });
  }

  requestPushNotif() {
    this._messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('have permission');
        return this._messaging.getToken();
      })
      .then(function(token) {
        console.log(token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: The token might not be generated yet by the time you call `getToken()`. That's why you must also implement `onTokenRefresh()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#monitor-token-refresh

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried it but without more luck. I've edited my first message. Did I miss something?

Comment: Hmmm.... in that case I don't know. I haven't tried FCM.js with angular myself, but that combination should not make any difference. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem for you, so that I can try it?

Comment: Actually It works in firefox but not in chrome. I get a token in firefox. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution. The problem came from the relation between the Angular-CLI and AngularFire2.

It's [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md#troubleshooting).

I had to add the following in `src/tsconfig.json` and in `src/typings.d.ts`:

```
"types": [
  "firebase"
]
```

and

```
declare var require: any;
declare var module: any;
```

I hope this can help someone.

Thank you, Frank van Puffelen, for your help. You are always here to help on my firebase questions :)

**EDIT** I just found out that it does not work in all browser. It works in firefox but not in chrome... How come ?

Comment: Worked for me on chrome 60. Maybe they fixed something ? Actually, just the `src/tsconfig.json` edit was enough.